# laravel4.2のbladeで常にhtmlspecialcharsを通して{{ & }} で &amp; が出力されるようにしたい

Tags: laravel

laravelのbladeにて出力するときに常に htmlspecialchars を通したいです。
bladeを拡張、または上書きするような形になると思うのですが、どう実装すればよいか教えていただけますでしょうか？
laravel4.2を使用しております。

Answer (score 1):

データをエスケープして出したいだけでしたら、{{{ }}}でエスケープされて表示されます。

http://readouble.com/laravel/4/2/0/ja/templates.html#other-blade-control-structures

Comment: データをエスケープしたいというのはその通りなのですが、
{{ }} で実現できないかなと考えております
ソースの修正箇所が多いもので...

Comment: なるほど。  
ではBladeのsetContentTagsメソッドをstart/global.phpなりに記述すると良いと思います。  
(なお、5系にする場合はAppServiceProviderのbootメソッドに書くのがよいでしょう)

`\Blade::setContentTags('{{{', '}}}');`    
`\Blade::setContentTags('{{', '}}', true);`    

第３引数がエスケープタグかどうかなので、{{の方をtrueににします。